# How can I put multiple items into a JSON object with CoffeeScript?

Tags: json, coffeescript

```
  categories = {{"code": "zzz", "title": "Electronics"}, {"code": "yyy", "title": "Cars"}};
```

That's my JavaScript. What's the equivalent CoffeeScript?

Comment: That doesn't look like correct javascript, did you mean to declare an array [{/**/},{/**}] with square brackets?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Braces are optional in CoffeeScript, you can have either this:

```
categories = [
  code  : 'zzz'
  title : 'Electronics'
,
  code  : 'yyy'
  title : 'Mechanics'
]
```

(notice the unindented comma) or the more obvious:

```
categories = [
  {
    code  : 'zzz'
    title : 'Electronics'
  }, // comma optional
  {
    code  : 'yyy'
    title : 'Mechanics'
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think your JavaScript should look like this:

```
categories = [{"code": "zzz", "title": "Electronics"}, {"code": "yyy", "title": "Cars"}];
```

You do want an array, correct? Then the CoffeeScript is, well, exactly the same (without the trailing semicolon but that's also optional in JavaScript):

```
categories = [{"code": "zzz", "title": "Electronics"}, {"code": "yyy", "title": "Cars"}]
```

There's a "TRY COFFEESCRIPT" button at the top of the [Github CoffeeScript page](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/) that you might find useful for things like this.